# Estimate lag for granger causality test

Tags: r, time-series, computational-statistics, granger-causality

I am using the granger causality test to check my variables for causality.+

Here is my code:

```
>library(MSBVAR)
> dput(datSel)
structure(list(oenb_dependent = c(142.8163942, 143.5711365, 145.3485827, 
142.0577145, 139.4326176, 140.1236581, 138.6560282, 136.405036, 
133.9337229, 133.8785538, 132.0608441, 130.0866307, 120.1320237, 
119.6368882, 114.3312943, 117.5084111, 114.4960017, 112.9124518, 
112.8185478, 112.3047916, 106.632639, 106.2107158, 106.8455028, 
106.3879556, 104.3451786, 102.9085952, 101.0967783, 101.7858278, 
101.0749044, 102.6441976, 102.0666152, 100, 97.14084104, 97.49972913, 
96.91453836, 96.05132443, 94.98057971, 92.78373451, 92.67526281, 
91.82430571, 91.4153859, 89.51740671, 89.01587176, 84.62259911, 
91.48598494, 89.12053042, 90.02364352, 90.92496121, 89.42963565, 
91.93886583, 88.83918306, 90.39513509, 87.54571761, 91.3386451, 
87.7836994, 91.79178376, 87.56903138, 87.77875755, 89.29938784, 
90.88084014), gdp = c(17703.7, 17599.8, 17328.2, 17044, 17078.3, 
16872.3, 16619.2, 16502.4, 16332.5, 16268.9, 16094.7, 15956.5, 
15785.3, 15587.1, 15460.9, 15238.4, 15230.2, 15057.7, 14888.6, 
14681.1, 14566.5, 14384.1, 14340.4, 14383.9, 14549.9, 14843, 
14813, 14668.4, 14685.3, 14569.7, 14422.3, 14233.2, 14066.4, 
13908.5, 13799.8, 13648.9, 13381.6, 13205.4, 12974.1, 12813.7, 
12562.2, 12367.7, 12181.4, 11988.4, 11816.8, 11625.1, 11370.7, 
11230.1, 11103.8, 11037.1, 10934.8, 10834.4, 10701.3, 10639.5, 
10638.4, 10508.1, 10472.3, 10357.4, 10278.3, 10031), employ = c(71.0619, 
70.9383, 71.162, 71.138, 71.2286, 71.5095, 71.565, 71.3246, 71.4963, 
71.3738, 71.4276, 71.3065, 71.0246, 71.3244, 71.0619, 70.9811, 
71.2149, 70.8342, 70.5568, 70.5444, 70.3286, 70.179, 70.2555, 
70.5103, 70.8038, 70.6748, 70.9769, 70.6988, 70.2125, 70.1661, 
69.6284, 69.5613, 68.9837, 68.8606, 68.4223, 67.963, 67.6293, 
67.5905, 67.1857, 67.1248, 66.7075, 66.5857, 66.4303, 66.2826, 
68.7514, 68.8897, 69.0824, 68.9718, 68.7927, 68.6387, 68.8053, 
68.7286, 68.4141, 68.2357, 68.4785, 68.4171, 68.4782, 68.3978, 
68.5344, 68.4772), atx = c(2160.080078, 2203.939941, 2500.850098, 
2523.820068, 2546.54, 2528.449951, 2223.97998, 2352.01001, 2401.21, 
2089.73999, 1975.349976, 2159.060059, 1891.68, 1947.849976, 2766.72998, 
2882.179932, 2947.24, 2541.629883, 2278.800049, 2634, 2495.56, 
2637.280029, 2098.649902, 1696.619995, 1750.83, 2767.76001, 3943.149902, 
3765.909912, 4512.98, 4527.299805, 4869.259766, 4645.5, 4463.47, 
3868.27002, 3745.719971, 4139.830078, 3667.03, 3457.449951, 3049.909912, 
2632.899902, 2431.38, 2042.869995, 1989.400024, 1866.76001, 1545.15, 
1351.890015, 1305.709961, 1163.109985, 1150.05, 1070.209961, 
1243.069946, 1289.16, 1140.36, 1084.069946, 1206.819946, 1186.540039, 
1073.3, 1161.160034, 1129.579956, 1130.069946), un.employ = c(5.7393, 
5.7072, 5.6126, 5.6411, 5.5114, 5.4551, 5.1613, 5.4087, 5.0227, 
5.2039, 4.9501, 4.5008, 4.9143, 4.1372, 4.5604, 4.7979, 4.5454, 
4.8863, 5.0496, 4.9757, 5.4705, 5.8403, 5.4328, 4.6986, 4.4481, 
4.1385, 3.8379, 4.2183, 4.5429, 5.03, 5.1821, 4.8269, 5.0469, 
5.1054, 5.3959, 5.5413, 5.8139, 5.8611, 5.8396, 5.1964, 5.6386, 
5.6615, 5.5751, 5.2251, 4.4682, 4.262, 4.3487, 4.1654, 3.9651, 
3.9105, 3.7954, 4.1595, 3.8174, 3.6349, 3.6119, 3.4004, 3.366, 
3.3953, 3.3621, 3.9338), carReg = c(88.548662, 90.58853576, 91.32289522, 
91.56290683, 108.4682322, 93.86541244, 100.3414441, 91.98328561, 
95.53905246, 102.6461104, 97.9505881, 108.912959, 114.4931447, 
108.0431511, 98.58118608, 107.9440773, 99.41777306, 104.868483, 
100.3338425, 98.06667712, 100.6353811, 100.6491181, 106.4241282, 
79.3180456, 80.40781739, 85.35716451, 102.9110831, 88.99947733, 
99.38928861, 87.57579615, 87.49264945, 90.29013182, 92.13878645, 
90.15141711, 83.90950016, 97.24552675, 93.38024804, 94.16745797, 
98.90106448, 94.73366108, 104.1079291, 98.20132446, 97.70974526, 
91.86162897, 101.5381154, 94.56938821, 86.91581151, 87.16428746, 
87.35114009, 85.0634706, 86.2179337, 82.34156437, 79.86840987, 
84.20717658, 85.29553997, 90.94079268, 92.84823122, 88.90113767, 
88.05502443, 92.38787475), cpi = c(363.81, 361.19, 362.35, 359.09, 
359.31, 355.8, 356.64, 353.83, 353.49, 348.92, 348.8, 344.85, 
343.48, 340.75, 341.1, 335.72, 331.29, 328.21, 328.95, 325.92, 
324.83, 322.83, 323.18, 321.66, 322.94, 323.14, 322.89, 318.34, 
315.85, 311.61, 311.3, 308.34, 306.1, 305.64, 305.58, 302.91, 
301.64, 300.24, 299.54, 298.58, 296.4, 293.87, 293.35, 291.61, 
289.43, 288.03, 287.69, 287.6, 285.95, 284.8, 284.63, 282.62, 
281.24, 280, 280.09, 277.65, 275.73, 273.12, 272.78, 272.25), 
    prodPrice = c(307.5, 308.6, 308.9, 309.7, 311.1, 311.6, 311.6, 
    313.9, 314.9, 314.8, 314.9, 314.5, 313.4, 313, 312.9, 309, 
    304.5, 302.76, 299.28, 293.44, 291.52, 291.71, 290.61, 294.17, 
    297.74, 300.02, 295.91, 292.9, 289.23, 287.49, 285.86, 283.84, 
    281.1, 280.37, 278.63, 275.44, 273.88, 273.24, 274.6, 275.15, 
    269.77, 267.66, 264.29, 262.27, 260.53, 260.52, 261.54, 263.27, 
    261.45, 261.81, 261.99, 261.35, 262.64, 264.74, 265.56, 265.47, 
    267.3, 265.47, 262.64, 260.72), productionConstr = c(103.3086091, 
    102.9085757, 103.6086341, 107.5089591, 107.9089924, 108.9090758, 
    104.3086924, 97.80815068, 104.8087341, 108.0090008, 103.4086174, 
    104.5087091, 105.8088174, 100.308359, 102.6085507, 100.4083674, 
    96.80806734, 99.50829236, 102.708559, 100.7083924, 103.0485874, 
    103.9186599, 104.7887324, 105.0787566, 103.3386116, 104.0186682, 
    102.5685474, 112.4193683, 105.8488207, 104.5987166, 107.3989499, 
    108.6490541, 107.2989416, 106.2388532, 101.3084424, 98.02816901, 
    102.1785149, 97.83815318, 98.70822569, 88.85740478, 92.66772231, 
    95.36794733, 91.4076173, 87.54729561, 89.66747229, 87.73731144, 
    87.34727894, 90.9275773, 78.26652221, 80.29669139, 79.90665889, 
    77.68647387, 77.59646637, 78.46653888, 77.68647387, 77.01641803, 
    84.45703809, 77.97649804, 76.72639387, 77.88649054), constrPriceIndex = c(109.1, 
    109.1, 108.8, 108.2, 107.6, 107.2, 107.3, 106.7, 106.4, 106, 
    105.9, 104.9, 103.8, 103.5, 103, 102.3, 101.3, 100.5, 99.6, 
    98.6, 97.43314, 96.68301, 95.84954, 95.18276, 94.76602, 94.01589, 
    92.84903, 91.18208, 89.76517, 89.18174, 88.51496, 87.76484, 
    86.68132, 85.93119, 85.18107, 84.51429, 83.76416, 83.43077, 
    83.26407, 82.93068, 82.46215, 82.14979, 81.83744, 81.05654, 
    80.43183, 80.35374, 80.27565, 79.9633, 79.72903, 79.57285, 
    79.57285, 79.26049, 79.02623, 79.10432, 79.02623, 78.71387, 
    78.4796, 78.24534, 77.93298, 77.69871), constrCostTotal = c(108.26667, 
    107.96667, 107.46667, 106.76667, 106.66667, 106.6, 106.43333, 
    105.83333, 105, 104.8, 104.46667, 103.46667, 102.4, 102.56667, 
    102.2, 101.96667, 100.77774, 100.47032, 100.41443, 98.48607, 
    97.47997, 97.22844, 96.55771, 96.52976, 96.58566, 98.2066, 
    96.58566, 94.0704, 92.00231, 92.03026, 91.86257, 90.40932, 
    89.26348, 88.84427, 87.19538, 85.32292, 84.28887, 83.61814, 
    83.72993, 83.59019, 83.22324, 82.61167, 82.09794, 80.36107, 
    78.86882, 78.42849, 77.93923, 77.05856, 76.39806, 76.34913, 
    76.22682, 75.39507, 75.05259, 75.24829, 75.12598, 74.34316, 
    74.04961, 73.60927, 73.21786, 72.67968), primConstTot = c(108.56667, 
    108.56667, 108.23333, 107.3, 107.13333, 106.8, 106.63333, 
    105.76667, 105.46667, 105.06667, 104.8, 103.23333, 102.5, 
    102.6, 102.36667, 102.1, 100.5226, 100.32976, 100.71544, 
    98.29121, 97.35458, 97.43723, 96.80362, 96.85872, 96.36285, 
    98.75953, 97.05155, 93.6907, 91.12874, 91.29403, 91.29403, 
    89.44831, 88.07091, 87.57505, 85.86707, 83.96626, 83.4153, 
    82.64396, 82.47867, 82.17564, 82.00498, 81.76645, 81.12244, 
    79.59587, 78.02161, 77.73538, 77.18677, 76.11341, 75.39783, 
    75.42168, 75.04004, 73.94283, 73.94283, 74.08594, 73.7043, 
    72.67864, 72.2493, 71.89151, 71.43831, 70.62732), baumeisterarbeit = c(57844L, 
    57844L, 57667L, 57168L, 57080L, 56904L, 56813L, 56353L, 56193L, 
    55980L, 55838L, 55003L, 54612L, 54666L, 54541L, 54398L, 53567L, 
    53465L, 53670L, 52379L, 51878L, 51923L, 51585L, 51615L, 51351L, 
    52629L, 51718L, 49927L, 48562L, 48649L, 48640L, 47666L, 46932L, 
    46668L, 45758L, 44745L, 44428L, 44046L, 43944L, 43779L, 43690L, 
    43563L, 43219L, 42407L, 41567L, 41416L, 41123L, 40551L, 40170L, 
    40182L, 39979L, 39395L, 39394L, 39471L, 39267L, 38721L, 38514L, 
    38309L, 38061L, 37617L), gesamtbaukost = c(59373L, 59209L, 
    58935L, 58551L, 58496L, 58458L, 58368L, 58039L, 57582L, 57472L, 
    57289L, 56742L, 56156L, 56248L, 56046L, 55919L, 55243L, 55075L, 
    55045L, 53988L, 53436L, 53298L, 52930L, 52915L, 52947L, 53834L, 
    52946L, 51567L, 50433L, 50449L, 50357L, 49557L, 48932L, 48671L, 
    47722L, 46772L, 46213L, 45865L, 45919L, 45826L, 45612L, 45276L, 
    44994L, 44041L, 43225L, 42983L, 42715L, 42232L, 41870L, 41843L, 
    41777L, 41321L, 41132L, 41240L, 41172L, 40743L, 40587L, 40352L, 
    40127L, 39814L), lohn = c(96819L, 96819L, 96090L, 94632L, 
    94632L, 94632L, 93727L, 91917L, 91917L, 91917L, 90779L, 88503L, 
    88416L, 88416L, 88270L, 87978L, 87996L, 87996L, 87566L, 86706L, 
    86706L, 86706L, 85794L, 83970L, 83970L, 83970L, 83007L, 81081L, 
    81081L, 81081L, 80423L, 79107L, 79107L, 79107L, 78321L, 76749L, 
    76533L, 76533L, 75983L, 74883L, 74883L, 74883L, 74575L, 73959L, 
    73959L, 73959L, 73167L, 71583L, 71583L, 71583L, 70858L, 69408L, 
    69408L, 69408L, 68594L, 66966L, 66831L, 66342L, 65853L, 64875L
    ), resProp.Dwell = c(144.5, 146.5, 147.3, 143.3, 140.1, 142.8, 
    141.2, 140.2, 137.8, 137.4, 136.6, 137.6, 125.5, 125.7, 120.5, 
    124.2, 121.5, 119.8, 121.3, 122, 114.1, 114.4, 114.7, 116.1, 
    112.8, 111.8, 110.2, 111.7, 112.2, 113.7, 112.7, 110.5, 107, 
    107.5, 108, 107.1, 106.7, 103.3, 104.2, 104.3, 104.1, 101.3, 
    100.5, 94.3, 105.6, 101, 102, 103.1, 101.4, 105.5, 100.5, 
    102.8, 100.5, 105.1, 98.8, 105.1, 98.2, 98.2, 100.6, 103), 
    resProp.Dwell.1 = c(132.2, 133.9, 133.5, 126, 125, 122.6, 
    122.6, 123.8, 124.5, 120.2, 120.2, 123.5, 105.2, 116.4, 111.5, 
    116.4, 116.1, 114.3, 117, 117.9, 107.1, 104.5, 110.6, 110.5, 
    104.2, 105.4, 106.2, 110.3, 106.8, 111.4, 111.2, 108.5, 93.5, 
    101.5, 101.4, 101.3, 101.7, 96.8, 97.3, 100, 97.5, 99.4, 
    94.8, 93.8, 101.9, 97.4, 97.7, 98.4, 100.6, 100.1, 96.3, 
    98.1, 93.4, 99.3, 97.3, 99.6, 99.2, 97.8, 100.1, 102.9), 
    resProp.Dwell.2 = c(149.8, 151.9, 153.2, 150.7, 146.5, 151.5, 
    149.2, 147.3, 143.6, 144.8, 143.6, 143.7, 134.1, 129.7, 124.3, 
    127.5, 123.7, 122.2, 123.1, 123.8, 117.1, 118.6, 116.4, 118.4, 
    116.4, 114.6, 111.9, 112.2, 114.5, 114.6, 113.4, 111.3, 112.8, 
    110.1, 110.8, 109.5, 108.8, 106.1, 107.1, 106.1, 107, 102.1, 
    103, 94.5, 107.2, 102.5, 103.9, 105.1, 101.7, 107.8, 102.4, 
    104.8, 103.6, 107.6, 99.5, 107.4, 97.8, 98.4, 100.8, 103), 
    resProp.Dwell.3 = c(155.2, 157.6, 159, 156.5, 151.4, 155, 
    152, 149, 146.4, 147.9, 146.6, 146.3, 137.1, 131.1, 124.5, 
    127.5, 123.1, 121.9, 123, 123.5, 116.4, 117.7, 116.4, 118.1, 
    116.5, 113.7, 110.2, 111, 113.9, 113.9, 113.6, 110.9, 113.2, 
    109.9, 111.7, 109.7, 110.1, 106.3, 107.4, 105.9, 107.2, 101.6, 
    103.8, 94.1, 108.4, 102.7, 104.1, 105.1, 101.5, 108.8, 102.3, 
    105.4, 103, 107.2, 99.3, 107.6, 97.4, 97.6, 101.2, 103.9), 
    resProp.Dwell.4 = c(112.6, 112.7, 113.6, 110.7, 113.4, 127.1, 
    130.1, 135.7, 123.7, 123.2, 123, 125.5, 113.5, 120.2, 123.3, 
    128, 128.2, 124.6, 124, 125.8, 122.2, 124.8, 116.6, 120.4, 
    115.9, 120.6, 124, 120.6, 119, 120.1, 111.6, 114, 110.2, 
    111.6, 104.5, 107.9, 100.4, 104.7, 105, 106.9, 105.1, 105.8, 
    97.3, 96.6, 99.1, 101.1, 102.5, 105.2, 103, 101, 102.7, 100.5, 
    107.4, 110.1, 101.3, 105.7, 100.3, 104.1, 98.4, 97.2)), .Names = c("oenb_dependent", 
"gdp", "employ", "atx", "un.employ", "carReg", "cpi", "prodPrice", 
"productionConstr", "constrPriceIndex", "constrCostTotal", "primConstTot", 
"baumeisterarbeit", "gesamtbaukost", "lohn", "resProp.Dwell", 
"resProp.Dwell.1", "resProp.Dwell.2", "resProp.Dwell.3", "resProp.Dwell.4"
), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
> granger <- granger.test(datSel, 4)
```

As you can see the second argument of the `granger.test` function should be the lag. However, I do not know how to estimate this properly.

Any suggestion how to estimate the `lag` for the granger causality test?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I believe the lag should be selected so as to yield a good model for the CPI and the wages. As is usual, you could use information criteria and look at the properties of model residuals. The fact that it will be used for Granger test does not require special treatment. However, check for caveats (e.g. case of cointegrated series) in Dave Giles [blog post](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Introduction

This test in your question seems rather heavy handed. It is conducting pairwise bivariate Granger causality testing over all pairs in the data set. I'll choose two to examine.

```
require(lmtest)


ts(datSel$cpi)->cpi

ts(datSel$lohn)->wages #i presume
```

Note that in your test at lag order 4 we get that both wages Granger cause cpi and cpi Granger causes wages. Is this lag order appropriate?

#### The bigger problem

We have a much bigger problem though first. Neither wages nor cpi are stationary. We'll take the first difference of the logs of these indices to achieve plausible stationarity.

```
d.cpi<-diff(log(cpi))
d.wages<-diff(log(wages))
```

With the differenced series and lag order 4, we now have that wage increases Granger cause cpi increases (inflation) but not vice versa

```
lmtest::grangertest(d.wages,d.cpi,4)
```

```
Granger causality test

Model 1: d.cpi ~ Lags(d.cpi, 1:4) + Lags(d.wages, 1:4)
Model 2: d.cpi ~ Lags(d.cpi, 1:4)
  Res.Df Df      F  Pr(>F)  
1     46                    
2     50 -4 3.4826 0.01446 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
lmtest::grangertest(d.cpi,d.wages,4)
```

```
Granger causality test

Model 1: d.wages ~ Lags(d.wages, 1:4) + Lags(d.cpi, 1:4)
Model 2: d.wages ~ Lags(d.wages, 1:4)
  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1     46                 
2     50 -4 2.0651 0.1008
```

Note that these are simply a F-tests of two candidate models, one with lags of of the dependent variable only, the other also with lags of the independent variable.

#### The Problem Asked About

The other problem is how to choose an appropriate lag. If this data is quarterly, then a lag order of 4 is a great place to start. You might simply report the p-values for the F-tests from lag orders starting at the frequency of the data to twice the frequency, 4 to 8. In this case, the same conclusion would be reached at any of those lag orders.

One could also use AIC/BIC to select the lag length or use a series of F-tests on either increasing or decreasing lags. I'll use both AIC/BIC and F-tests of decreasing lags in this example.

```
select.lags<-function(x,y,max.lag=8) {
  y<-as.numeric(y)
  y.lag<-embed(y,max.lag+1)[,-1,drop=FALSE]
  x.lag<-embed(x,max.lag+1)[,-1,drop=FALSE]
  
  t<-tail(seq_along(y),nrow(y.lag))
  
  ms=lapply(1:max.lag,function(i) lm(y[t]~y.lag[,1:i]+x.lag[,1:i]))
  
  pvals<-mapply(function(i) anova(ms[[i]],ms[[i-1]])[2,"Pr(>F)"],max.lag:2)
  ind<-which(pvals<0.05)[1]
  ftest<-ifelse(is.na(ind),1,max.lag-ind+1)
  
  aic<-as.numeric(lapply(ms,AIC))
  bic<-as.numeric(lapply(ms,BIC))
  structure(list(ic=cbind(aic=aic,bic=bic),pvals=pvals,
    selection=list(aic=which.min(aic),bic=which.min(bic),ftest=ftest)))
}
```

Let's try this on `d.cpi~d.wages`.

```
s<-select.lags(d.wages,d.cpi,8)

t(s$selection)
```

```
     aic bic ftest
[1,] 5   5   5
```

In this case, the AIC, BIC, and series of F-tests all suggest a lag order of 5 out of 8. Looking at a plot of the ICs, we can see a local minimum at 5, which suggests that we might be satisfied here.

```
plot.ts(s$ic)
```

[image: IC for model lag order selection]

Note that in the opposite direction we also select 5 but do not have statistically significant Granger causality.

#### Conclusion

In this data set we have some evidence that wage increases temporally precede inflation increases and are useful in forecasting them, but not vice versa. Bivariate Granger causality testing must be performed on stationary data or conclusions may be spurious. Additional testing should be performed on the underlying regressions to check other assumptions of OLS, but has not been performed here. Lag order equal to frequency is often a good choice. Information criteria and F-tests may also be used.

Comment: Thx for your great answer! Indeed the data is quaterly. However, just to understand the beginning of your answer. How did you figure out that the data is not stationary?

Comment: If you plot either, you'll see they are indices rather than growth, with a clear trend, obviously not level stationary. You could attempt to detrend them, but you'd still likely encounter non-stationarity around the trend. Differencing usually takes care of both. The `tseries` library has unit root tests `kpss.test`, `adf.test`, and `pp.test`, which may be used. The `fUnitsRoots` and/or `urca` library contain versions with more flexibility. For example, `ur.df` in `urca` allows you to select the lag order for the ADF test using AIC/BIC as well as specify drift and trend components.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Just one more question about your answer! How would you do the lag selection for a data set like mine? Would you run through all possible combinations of datat?

Comment: Look at each variable to determine its level of integration. I(1) variables that are hypothesized to be temporally related can be put in a VAR model and tested for cointegration and causality together. Or difference as needed to I(0) and do pairwise, yes. For a lot of pairs I might check at 4 and 8 for quarterly data and investigate any discrepancies.

Comment: @Kare, could CPI and wages be cointegrated? If so, the recommended way to do the analysis is given in Dave Giles' [blog post](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) (see also related posts if necessary). In my opinion, it is an excellent tutorial.

Comment: It seems that in your select.lags function you maintain each lag in the same size with `embed`, whereas the `grangertest` function mantains the maximum observations in each estimation.